# same generic type as input and output

Tags: typescript

Function `decode_json()` takes JSON and decode all keys from any object found.

Example: `a` key found in JSON is `latitude` (decoded). Why? `a` has index of 0 from `alphabet` variable and `latitude` has index of 0 too from `keys` variable.

[TS playground link HERE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwA4As4CMCmsC8MDkGwAJpgGYDmKAlgFYDWCAtmCEgI4BO0ArgG4B3AB4BPAF74A3AChpmIUhCdYpMnB4JYZHmGBRq4GKVCkA%20rQjgAPABUAjAD4AFBfAAuGPYCUH%20zADe0jAw1GQwTgCCnJxwIgB01BBRMSIulmBeXjCc2DycYDCuYHFMcEhOxiBmRV4yQSFhTlAiSJggYUUwON0EIOi0mHr4XvXBOVB5BQDy-YNQcZhgUJzUmBBp4F5xOcQ8wJhW-jAA2vSYIh7QK2AUALq%20djAAvs5OCAA02Vk4DgGjwQ1wslYgkktFYk5OMc7LdMn8AQiYAhjpVSABpc6Q44ABlhty62WhtxKZQqgyqmHM6Vq-wR40mSJkiOesmZoXCzVa7UJMK6PXwfQGQyygWZwWRqMwGNSUNxXnxeElVPAWJhNLF2Vy%20UZtJZuol5PRmNleIJUJhdWZ9O1CCZAKen38Txp9WtBSKMiesm0un0hkl0qcZwuMCu1BuPlDy3DFHhgKciFQGGwCTApCEUzIQfOWQAhD0ALR2LJumDBiDHRNoLDzcPpzPZkTyy0wKAoTggAQwMCYLsAUWiSicAAMbChMGXzjAAEQAEn8wae06MIDW3ZAsHkiXmw5pXukoEgsHLl2jN2OCpO9XwCDg%20gmpHw72vCHAFGoD8wT%20kt0kQA)

### Issue

Line 4

```
TS2322: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T1'.
'T1' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'any[]'.
```

#### Code

```js
const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

export default function decode_json<T1>(json: T1): T1 {
  if (Array.isArray(json)) return json.map(decode_json);

  if (typeof json === 'object')
    return Object.entries(json).reduce<{ [key: string]: T1 }>((l, r) => {
      if (Array.isArray(r[1])) {
        l[decodeKey(r[0])] = r[1].map(decode_json);
        return l;
      }

      if (typeof r[1] === 'object') {
        l[decodeKey(r[0])] = decode_json(r[1]);
        return l;
      }

      l[decodeKey(r[0])] = r[1];

      return l;
    }, {});

  return json;
}

function decodeKey(key: string): string {
  if (alphabet.indexOf(key) !== -1) return keys[alphabet.indexOf(key)];

  throw new Error(`The key "${key}" does not exist.`);
}

const keys: string[] = [
  'latitude',
  'longitude',
];
```

#### minimal example

function will add "blabla" as suffix to every single key in object or array of objects

```
function addBlabla<T1>(json: T1): T1 {
  if (Array.isArray(json)) return json.map(addBlabla);

  if (typeof json === "object")
    return Object.entries(json).reduce<{ [key: string]: T1 }>((l, r) => {
      l[r[0] + "blabla"] = r[1];

      return l;
    }, {});

  return json;
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoEIBtkCMcA8AKgIwB8AFAFYDOCAXIqQJSOmIDeAsAFCKIxgiCgEEATmOQBPAHQwa4yVOp0wzZojEBTKCDFJaCGQFtkABwppMOfMmYBuXr36DhUKWa1whhpAF4AxAAiOFwqLWgg5md%20TR09JAB5MIioGS0wKDEYLRoVBGYZbVQQCC0CDkQAbQBrLSlGGiyYMABzAF02EkQAX0oKLAAaTQ0-Mk4Y2MQsKrEqgAZ2xABqYNtbIKW-TSqSdsceSdjtXX1pg6me4Y4ehyc%20ONODVQOeoA)

Comment: The compiler can't possibly understand that, for example, `json.map(decode_json)` will return a value of the same type as `json`.  And neither can I, frankly, because you haven't explained what it does in detail or shown examples of what it's doing.  Clearly though if I pass in `decode_json([{a: number}])` what comes out is not `Array<{a: 1}>`, as you said.  So the compiler is right to complain.  Even if you manage to express at the type level what `decode_json` does, the compiler wouldn't be able to verify the implementation works for unspecified generics.

Comment: There's a bit too much confusion in the question for me to write up an answer that isn't ten pages long.  Maybe you could reduce the code to a [mre] with just one error you are concerned about, where the input/output relationship is the simplest possible one that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for answer... i added minimal example as a part of my question

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wol38w) meet your needs?  Note that the output is absolutely not the same type as the input.

Comment: Going from your minimal example: your function *doesn't* return something of the same type as its input. If you pass in the object `{foo: 1}` of type `{foo: number}`, then you get out the object `{fooblabla: 1}` which is not of type `{foo: number}`. So of course you are going to get an error.

Comment: @jcalz why do you use the function overloading... is not the first definition enough? it has to be `(json: any)`?

Comment: As I said before, even if you manage to express at the type level what the function does (e.g., `<T>(json: T) => BlaBla<T>`), the compiler will not be able to *verify* that the implementation works since the types are of unspecified generics like `T`.  It's not smart enough to see that `if (Array.isArray(json)) return json.map(addBlabla)` produces `BlaBla<T>`.  We need to do the equivalent of a type assertion.  I can replace the overloads with a bunch of `as` all over the place like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2Kx9N); is that better? But it's not possible to get the compiler to "see" it itself.

Comment: So, do you want this as an answer or do you want something else?

Comment: damn it u are hero of mine... create an answer please

Comment: @jcalz one more question... is "Extract" necessary? it will only pick a "string" from keys... am i right? but can be a key something else?

Comment: A key can be a `number` or `symbol`.  You can maybe add `blabla` to a number to get `"2blabla"` but you can't do a `symbol`; so you need `Extract` or something like it.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB: I'm only going to work on the minimal example; it can be extended to your original version if needed, but I'll leave that to you.

---

The big issue here is that your function's output is definitely not the same type as its input.  If you call `addBlabla(json)` where `json` is of type `{a: number}`, the return type will be `{ablabla: number}`.  Those are not the same, and so if the `json` function parameter is of type `T`, you cannot claim that the return type is also `T`.

What *is* the return type if the input is of type `T`, which we shall call `Blabla<T>`?  Well, we can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) and [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to express what happens.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type Blabla<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? { [K in keyof T]: Blabla<T[K]> } :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T as `${Exclude<K, symbol>}blabla`]: T[K] } : T;
```

This is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks if `T` is arraylike (`readonly any[]` is more permissive than `any[]`) and, if so, [maps it to a new array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where the elements each have `Blabla<>` applied to them.

If `T` is a non-arraylike object, we re-map each key from `K` to `` `${Exclude<K, symbol>}blabla` ``.  This uses a template literal type to append `"blabla"` to the end of the key.  Note that [`keyof T` can include `symbol`-typed keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types) but template literal types cannot append to symbols, so we use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to suppress any `symbol`-valued keys.  (In your implementation, [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will exclude `symbol` keys anyway, so this is the right thing to do.)

Finally, if `T` is not an array or an object, the type evaluates to just `T`.

So the type of `addBlaBla` will look like:

```
function addBlabla<T>(json: T): Blabla<T> { /* impl */ }
```

---

At this point you will start running into the same errors as before if you just use your implementation as-is.  Inside the implementation, the type `T` is an *unspecified* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  And the compiler is unable to do very sophisticated analysis on such types.

When you write

```
if (Array.isArray(json)) return json.map(addBlabla);
```

the compiler can use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow `json` from type `T` to something like `T & any[]`, and it lets you call `map()`.  But what it does *not* do is narrow the type parameter `T` itself.  And so it has no idea if `json.map(addBlabla)` will result in `Blabla<T>`.

The type `Blabla<T>` is essentially *opaque* to the compiler inside the implementation of `addBlabla()`.  This is either a current or permanent design limitation in Typescript.  The canonical issue in GitHub about this is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), but there are other related issues.  For now, we just can't expect the compiler to figure out that any particular value will be assignable to `Blabla<T>` for unspecified generic `T`.

---

That means we need to work around it.  In cases where *you* know what type a value is but *the compiler* doesn't, you can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what it doesn't know:

```
function addBlabla<T>(json: T): Blabla<T> {
  if (Array.isArray(json)) return json.map(addBlabla) as any as Blabla<T>;

  if (typeof json === "object")
    return Object.entries(json).reduce<{ [key: string]: T }>((l, r) => {
      l[r[0] + "blabla"] = r[1];
      return l;
    }, {}) as Blabla<T>;

  return json as Blabla<T>;
}
```

This now compiles without error.  You need to be careful not to *lie* to the compiler, so you should triple check that the assertion is accurate before doing so. For example, the following compiles with no error, even though the implementation is wrong:

```
function addBlablaBad<T>(json: T): Blabla<T> {
  return json as Blabla<T>; // this is a lie, but no error
}
```

---

It's a bit annoying to have to use `as Blabla<T>` three times in the code, so we can do something nearly equivalent to type assertions: a single-call-signature [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function addBlabla<T>(json: T): Blabla<T>;
function addBlabla<T>(json: T) {
  if (Array.isArray(json)) return json.map(addBlabla);

  if (typeof json === "object")
    return Object.entries(json).reduce<{ [key: string]: T }>((l, r) => {
      l[r[0] + "blabla"] = r[1];
      return l;
    }, {});

  return json;
}
```

Overloaded function implementations are checked more loosely than regular functions, so the compiler is happy with the above.  It's just as unsafe as type assertions, so you should really check the implementation just as much as before.  For example, no error here:

```
function addBlablaBad<T>(json: T): Blabla<T>;
function addBlablaBad<T>(json: T) {
  return json; // this is a lie, but no error
}
```

So be careful!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&module=1&ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgNgQwEaIDwBUB8UC8V1QQAewEAdgCYDOUAThAhQPZlwhQJkgDaAulAH4oAbyjcA0lACWZKAGsIIJgDN8vAFyxEKBBgm9sAXyjqAsACgo+QiXLUoTJACsIAY2CCRYyTPmKV1gg0AAYAJMIAokSucACuFBCo4gA0UFQgALZITHCYhjo6wRr4+lDGmugA3BYWZAgZEFRgCK7QACJuiPQiFlYJMQjdyrFk7lIsHBQU8MhoWAAUTlQsFQCUmjM6GJjV5oY15sOjwOOyjNPac5iLy2RrG5e6WD2W0qrzAIK0tAggAHRSKhfH4gG4sVarOgQYCxWiyJYsP4ZBBgebnTaISFBDhcDg0DFPHYHKxSd6gSABBGyHA0qAAIkcLncdNWvSsUJhcKgAHlnG5gH9yMBaFJGmCyKs-vQKLFWqhRNwFCBNFRhTIAObFAiGa7zOCpWiQnDYYRs9lQODcWjcAAM-AA1PSCog6fw8NaAIy8Xbmqz0TmyOA+9mGVLCQxY-GPba7Nn+2Hw254rSzQm7fbmWr1RrNVo8gBucHspteRzGE3R0YWVPuKa2WGDZZOFamBO24rWL3NpKgn2+vwBQP7oKpEI5CagVKRKLRrceq1jrxJZPAEEpSZpeAZfOZrKX7PjXN5TIFQpFYtHUogMrlCqVKrVZE1FTKuv1dCNJrNvst1rtUEdOlnQQV1cDobgvWDX1xy5INvysUMRAjRdzUPRMWGDDM2SbU5JguVMYEYdsa3wdY6yuRsRnLM45wIojq1uTsS1Q6EJypTCDgsLDDio5saPwnRCIoYjGNIh5U22LsYPQs4owkhsuM48xXBYVUoFINS8ErVN5m4UQEE0D0ylSPSoCQTQACZjK8VxNAAZjKXgwygChNAAFkc5MVLIVUFwOAB6AAqKBvLUjTgE0ehGBYNgxGYg8GGYVh2FTHRDPTA1Epi9g9O-KKktipBgMsjKpL9LLkpC4qoDs9MnLKqFosqihqrcuqoEC-yDlCnIID+OAmHVeZwr88wgritk6VSl1DK4kz4qA4C6UsuapLpVwlvsrj6oWlrHmWqA3O2qxOqAA)

Comment: so you remove `json: any` (function argument)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Your answer is incredibly educational and must have cost you a lot of effort. I really appreciate your work. You made my day  Ďakujem zo 

Comment: i figured out that recursion does not work... if you implement "Array.isArray" into 2nd condition it will not work... Object can have a value of an another object... i need to add "blabla" here too

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/Na060w

Comment: Oof, you unaccepted the answer because I didn’t solve an issue outside the [mre]?  The reason I ask in comments “does this approach meet your needs” is to give you a chance to test it out on your use cases and then possibly [edit] the question with additional constraints *before* I work on an answer, so I don’t end up spending extra time and effort on something inapplicable. If your [mre] was *too* minimal for your use cases, it seems unfortunate to shift the burden of dealing with that to me.

Comment: My suggestion here would probably be to open a new question specifically with the recursion issue, since I can’t guarantee I will get to this anytime soon.

Comment: i created a new question... but u are the only one master of this issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808327/add-suffix-to-every-key-in-object-recursively

Comment: and i am also sorry for ur 1st answer... thanks for explanation