# add suffix to every key in object recursively

Tags: typescript

Function is minimized. It should add "blabla" to every single object key as suffix (recursively).

[TS playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Na060w)

### Error

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be
    unrelated to 'any[]'.
(2322)
```

### Input

```js
addBlabla([{ a: [{ b: 1 }] }])
```

### Output

```js
{
  ablabla: {
    b: number; // not a "bblabla"
  }[];
}[]
```

[TS playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Na060w)

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDGqRw) what you're looking for?  It looks like you just forgot to actually add `"blabla"` in the implementation (note that in cases like this, the compiler can't really help verify accuracy of the implementation, so you need to be careful).   And then I don't think you need to do anything in the reduce callback other than the recursive call to `addBlabla()`, which already knows what to do in cases of arrays, objects, and primitives.

Comment: @jcalz "b" key does not have a "blabla" suffix... but it must have it

Comment: Oof, you're right, sorry.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPAnW) work for you, then?  Let me know and I'll write up an answer if so.  Oh, I see you already answered your own question with that version.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the necessary code to reproduce directly as plaintext. Playground links are great but they're not a substitute for plaintext code.  See [ask] where it says "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Answer (score 0):

TS playground: https://tsplay.dev/wQKyVm

I removed `Array.isArray` part because Array is also object (typeof).

Comment: If you're going to write up your own answer, could you flesh it out so that it helps others?  Code should be in plain text in the question (in addition to the playground link, which is good to have), and hopefully there will be some sort of explanation in there about what you did and what was wrong with the code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You have two errors in the type declaration and the implementation.

In the type, you map every object to the type of himself instead of AddBlabla.

```js
type AddBlaBla<T> = T extends readonly any[]
  ? { [K in keyof T]: AddBlaBla<T[K]> }
  : T extends object
  // ? { [K in keyof T as `${Exclude<K, symbol>}blabla`]: T[K] } // replace this
  ? { [K in keyof T as `${Exclude<K, symbol>}blabla`]: AddBlaBla<T[K]> } // with this
  : T;
```

The implementation is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAQgGwIYtQHgCoD4oC8U2UEAHsBAHZwDOUAThKnAPZXIhSpUgDaAXQCwAKChQA-FADeUPgGkoASypQA1hBCsAZsQEAuWAgwYcCgfgC+o8YZLlKNeqwBGAKwgBjYDcky5iirqmjrE3PQABgAk0gCiZJ7IAK5wEJjyADRQtCAAti6syLiWLmilqBEGRkhoptjmVr52ANyiotpJVN5K7NzGZWg4uAAUbrTsdgCUhvA16IN4rSIdXcA9qixz5UOj41RTMr5KusMwDAyoIAB0SrRnFyC77JOTjBDASQyqY+xXuahgYabDDlSZLI4nUCQUI-VQEeFQABErg83kRk184iYHy+UAA8u4vMArtRgAwlBBaE8qJMrkw4ElPBBhsNkFkGK8CPhpJjxMoTvdLjc7udLsMGHwAIwCF6HMR8hXIPjivgABhlAGpEeVyoiBIRGFKBH8AUD+qhQUsFQrsZ9VMgrdbrCJeeJjlBhlCIKEJdLCAjkYS0a8efLrVAlRL1VqdWg9QbgQNUCrpWDXXzbbiHennenI2qBDGk-GiL6BI6be87RGK1BLFlpJZwtxeGmXfLM989ktcyIAPQAKl8nnYtGAUEoY8MofDFqT0-TCpchioSXyEAYzSgfb7UCorHHqCRsdQiJzgkdlkEogHfdEI6oY4nlPHRETc+TfFkqEMX6gy6gSU631SwZSWB9xmQCArmQVgAHNPRfNsgA).

Comment: ok but the error still shows in your example

Comment: I fixed the implementation. Check it now.

Comment: but it is not a fix... it is a lie to the compiler